Thingsboard PE, Missing totalizer data create strannge graph
I'm currently using Thingsboard PE for receiving and displaiing data from an IoT device.
The device send the total conter of pulses received since the installation.
The counter is sent automatically every 15 minutes with MQTT and I can see it inside the Thingsboard last telemetry for the device.
The connection to Thingboard MQTT broker is made with a 4G modem.
Everithing works fine as long asthe modem is connected to the network, some times the connection of the modem goes down and I have some missing datas.
When the modem reconnect to the network I need to wait for the sending periot of 15 minutes to receive new datas, the device do not cache unsended dati, it try to send and do not retry.
In thingsboard I will like to be able to show a Montly graph with the daily received pulses, but if data is missing for more than 1 day the graph start to be strange like in the image 1 where taller colums, like the one for 7 Aug is the sum of the missing bars for the previous days
Image 1
For the grap Series I've used the post-processing function
if (prevOrigValue) {
    return (value - prevOrigValue);
} else {
    return 0;
}


for extract the differences from the total during the plot, in this way I can change the time intervall and the difference is "always correct"
Inside thingsboard ther some ways to "reconstruct the missing datas"
